# Procedure Returning Blank Data Table from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, datatable, sqlcommand

I'm having issues with a stored procedure I'm attempting to run from an ASP.NET console application.

This is how I'm attempting to get the results in the code:

```
public static DataTable PerformStoredProcedure(int PracticeID, string CommandName)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnString"].ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = CommandName;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@practiceID", PracticeID);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + ",");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

After the procedure is run I get returned with a blank data set with no errors. However, when I run the procedure in SQL Server Management Studio I works just fine.

You may notice I don't use the `new SqlCommand()` constructor when initiating the `SqlCommand cmd`. That is because the query is enormous and takes a while to run so I figured it was a timeout issue.

Following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302038/how-to-set-sqlcommandtimeout-in-app-config), I made the following class in order to adjust the execution timeout limit.

```
class CommandFactory
{
            public static int CommandTimeout
            {
                get
                {
                    int commandTimeout = 0;
                    var configValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["commandTimeout"];

                    if (int.TryParse(configValue, out commandTimeout))
                        return commandTimeout;

                    return 120;
                }
            }
```

Figured I'd include that just to avoid confusion about whether the `SqlCommand` was being initialized correctly. After that adjustment, I began getting the issue where the command returns a blank data table. I assumed it could have to do with the minimum capacity of the data table `dt`, so I adjusted that as you can see in the original code.

I've done additional research and made the suggested fixes that are suggested to no avail:

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511374/my-stored-procedure-returns-something-but-sqldataadapter-fill-leaves-datatable) Set nocount on

[2.](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/310286/Stored-Procedure-returns-Empty-table-to-DATAREADER) Use data adapter instead of data reader

[3.](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1497882/Works-in-Management-Studio-but-not-from-C?PageIndex=1) This is the most detailed answer. There are several suggestions made with in the forum but the eventual resolution has to do with views being used by the database as a default and blocking access to desired data. I have already confirmed with our DBA that we do not do this.

Like I mentioned before, the query encompassed in the stored procedure is enormous and I haven't included it here because of its sheer size and because this post is long enough as it is. Again, I did confirm that the procedure is working in SSMS.

I also haven't included an example result set because the data contains restricted information.

I appreciate any help you can give.

UPDATE:

I added another method that calls a stored procedure to see if the problem was particular to the particular procedure being called. That second stored procedure also returned a blank data table so the problem is not specific to either procedure. (I also confirmed the second procedure was working and returning rows in SSMS)

That led me to believe there was something wrong with the app.config file for that project. I then added a third method that called a stored procedure on another project in the solution. However, even that returned a blank data table.

Figured I'd provide clues as I happen upon them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close. Here are a few pointers:

1. The `SqlConnection` is never opened. You need to call `.Open()` in order
   for the connection to be established.
2. If you set
   a breakpoint on the `.Fill()` line and hover over the `DataTable`
   object, it will appear as if the `DataTable` is empty (as you've seen), but `.Fill()` actually fills the `Rows` of the `DataTable` for you
   automatically (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx)). I bet that if you loop through the `Rows`, you'll find
   that your query has actually been returning data all along.
3. You could use `using` statements which automatically call `.Dispose()` for you as well as close the `SqlConnection`.

Here's an updated version of your method:

```
public static DataTable getAllModifiedChargesToday(int practiceID)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnString"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "ch_getAllModifiedChargesToday";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@practiceID", practiceID);

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

And here's a test you can run to view the data returned:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + ",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Also, you mentioned setting a timeout... I usually set my in my connection string, like so:

```
"Server=SERVER;Database=DATABASE;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Asynchronous Processing=true;Timeout=60;"
```

You don't need that extra `CommandFactory` class at all, and you don't need to set a `MinimumCapacity` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.minimumcapacity(v=vs.110).aspx)) unless you are really trying to optimize performance and have a guesstimate of how many records will be returned. This property isn't used very often.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the result of the command is still a blank {} datatable.

Comment: Didn't want to leave you hanging--I'll take another look at this when I get a chance.

Comment: Appreciate it brother.

Comment: Very interesting. I see how the Command Factory class isn't necessary. When I implemented your suggestions it still returned a blank data table for the original query but for the second query I mentioned in my edit it returned 7 rows as expected. I confirmed the original query was working in SSMS so I'm a little confused. I will do some more digging. Thank you though, you've been a great help

Comment: You're welcome. Could you post your updated code that still isn't working? Are you passing the same value for @practiceID in your testing as you are in SSMS?

Comment: Sure thing. Just so you know I changed the function name from getAllModifiedChargesToday to PerformStoredProcedure and added a parameter command name. This allows me to reuse the function for different procedures without having to make a new function for each one. Also yes, the practiceID being passed is definitely the same

Comment: Hmmm... Are there any other details you can offer? What rows do you expect, and what rows are being output to the log? The fact that this method is able to retrieve data by calling one of your stored procedures indicates that the application successfully connects to the database. So since you now have a means of retrieving data, I can only think that there have to be differences between the way the stored procedure is being called in your application vs. in SSMS. By the way, you may way to pass in a parameters array, since surely not every stored procedure expects the same parameters.

Comment: Very good point about sending an array of parameters instead of specified ones. Also, I have no idea why but when I ran the original SP from ASP.NET this morning it returned what I expected. I have no idea what is different from yesterday that's making it work and I'm concerned it may be inconsistent in the future. Anyways, marking yours as right answer for all your great help and the fact you tremendously improved the program. Thank you